# If $X,Y,Z$ are discrete random variables, then what is the definition of $\sum_{y \in Y}y \cdot P(\ y, Z=z, X=x)$?

Tags: probability

If $X,Y,Z$ are discrete random variables, then what is the definition of:

$$
\sum_{y \in Y}y \cdot P(\ y, Z=z, X=x)
$$

It seems very close to the definition of expectations, fixing $Z$ and $X$ at level $z,x$ respectively. Is there another way to see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the conditional expectation of $Y$ for given values $x,z$ of $X, Z$ respectively multiplied by the probability of that condition.

$$\mathsf E(Y\mid X{=}x, Z{=}z)\mathsf P(X{=}x, Z{=}z) ~=~ \sum\limits_{y \in Y(\Omega)}y \cdot\mathsf P(Y{=} y, Z{=}z, X{=}x)$$

Also written as $\mathsf E(Y; X{=}x, Z{=}z)$ or $\mathsf E(Y\,\mathbf 1_{X=x, Z=z})$, the expectation of the product of $Y$ and the indicator for the condition $X{=}x,Z{=}z$.